# Junit: NoSuchElement Exception while running test only in remotewebriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4, selenium-grid

I am running 10 tests in parallel with 2 nodes  using selenium grid , got an `NoSuchElementException` only in `Remotewebdriver` , but the same is working fine in normal firefox driver ,

I have definded my own threadpool executor class which holds two threads at a time , each thread starts its own Junit tests using Junitcore api.

below is the exception i recieved

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"login_element"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 1.28 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
>   Session ID: 5c94133a-5586-449c-b7f6-018bbd79a6d7
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotata
>   ble=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=23.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=tr
>   ue, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, ap
>   plicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:
>   39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorIm
>   pl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:356
>   )
>           at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:241)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.jav
>   a:101)
>           at $Proxy1.findElement(Unknown Source)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.
>   java:180)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:169)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Also tried a sample small tests , works fine without any exception , issue occurs only if i run my application

Please provide your inputs on this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wait for the element? I would suggest you to use `WebDriverWait`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120/*timeout in seconds*/);
WebElement login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login_element")));
//do stuff with login
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , the issue here is not about wait , its working fine when i run it through a normal firefox driver , but the same is not happening when i try it from a RemoteWebdriver and run tests parallely , so i doubt if there is any timeout issue , or any limitations on the perfomance when i run my selenium tests parallely

Comment: No matter whether you run locally or remotely using Explicit wait is recommended option. Are you saying, you tried explicitly wait like I suggested above and you still receive the exception?